# How do i make liteAccordion (horizontal accordion plugin for jQuery) work in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, css, internet-explorer-6

I am using [this Plugin](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/) and made some changes to fit to my requirement. Now this does not work in IE6. How to make it work in IE6 and IE8? How to adjust the CSS to make it to work?

http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does state in the documentation that IE6 is not supported by this plugin, so the easiest option might be to find an alternative plugin which does work in IE6. Or not to support IE6 yourself, of course.

If you really do need to support IE6 with this specific plugin, then you need to find out what CSS features it uses that aren't supported by IE6.

Looking at the [css file for the accordion on the demo page](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/css/liteaccordion.css), this includes the following:

- The `>` child selector.
- The `:hover` selector.
- `display: inline-block;`
- `border-radius`

and possibly more.

Some of this you can do without (`border-radius` for example), but most of them are definitely going to be required for the thing to work. The `>` child selector will be the big killer for you. Hover will also be a big issue.

You could try replacing the child selectors with descendant selectors -- ie replace the `>` symbols with a simple space. This does work in IE6, and often provides the same functionality. However it's likely that he's used the `>` rather than a space for a reason, which means that there's a good chance that this will break something. It's worth trying, but don't expect it to work straight off the bat. You're likely to need to do further work to get things back up and running.

To get the `:hover` working, you need to know that in IE6, `:hover` only works on `<a>` tags. So to fix the code, you'd need to rewrite it such that the elements that are affected by hovering are `<a>`.

If you want to avoid rewriting the whole thing, my suggestion would be to use a Javascript hack such as [Dean Edwards' IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). This is a javascript utility which attempts to add functionality to older versions of IE. This includes support for some CSS selectors. Another alternative that does a similar job is [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/).

The `:hover` CSS functionality can be forced to work in IE6 by using the [whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html) javascript hack. This is a neat little hack which makes hover work in IE6 for any element, not just `<a>` tags.

Adding one or more of these scripts to your site might be enough to get it working with the existing CSS. I can't guarantee it, but then it's hard to guarantee much with IE6.

The `border-radius` is non-essential but if you want that to work as well, the best hack for it is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). This works really well for adding rounded corner support in older versions of IE. However, with all the other hacks you'll be using, I would suggest not using it unless you have to, as all that javascript may cause performance problems in a browser as old as IE6.

Hope that helps.

Comment: :I tried all the Javascript hacks mentioned by you.none of them are working

Comment: @Someone - I've added another few paragraphs with more info. The hover hack may well help you. But if you want any more help with the other hacks, you need to say more about what isn't working -- have you tried seeing if they work with some simpler test case code? Have you read the documentation and made sure you've set them up correctly? Have they made *any* difference to your script? How bad exactly does this thing look in IE6 anyway? Have you tried tweaking the CSS as well, as I suggested (it won't get you all the way, but it might help)? And you have got Javascript turned on, right?